# How do I create a better control for rendering custom vue elements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a survey, that people can take.  However, if you are one of the first 1000 to fill out the survey you are given a reimbursement.  What I am struggling with is how to only show the reimbursement when the users are less than 1000.

The questions in the survey are coming from a CMS backend, while the reimbursement is built on the front end.

```js
<div class="questionContainer" v-if="intentGiven && consentGiven && !surveyComplete">
     <div v-if="$store.state.scoring.gameCompleted && this.index == this.QuestionnaireSize && this.ParticipantCount <= 1000">
        <ResearchQuestionReimbursement v-on:answered="advanceQuestion"/>
    </div>  
    <div v-else>
        <ResearchQuestionMultipleChoice :question="questions[index]"
            v-if="questions[index].Type == 'MultipleChoice'" 
            v-on:answered="advanceQuestion" />
        <ResearchQuestionFreeAnswer :question="questions[index]"
            v-if="questions[index].Type == 'FreeAnswer'" 
            v-on:answered="advanceQuestion" />
    </div>
</div>
```

`questions[index]` is an array of the questions received from the backend CMS.  The reimbursement is only supposed to be at the end which is why I have the `div` wrapped around `<ResearchQuestionReimbursement>`.

My control logic for the index is:

```
if (this.index < this.questions.length -1 || (this.$store.state.scoring.gameCompleted && this.index < this.questions.length)) {
    this.index++;
    console.log(`post: ${this.index}`)
} else {
.....
//required code to save the form
}
```

Currently, if I have over 1000 users the logic continues and gives me an index undefined error.  This makes sense since the index would be 13 and the array would only be 12.  I have tried a v-if on `<ResearchQuestionReimbursement>` to check if there are 1000 users.  This resulted in a blank page rendering since it rendered the div but not the content.

What it should do is if there are more than 1000 users it will skip to the else statement.

Comment: **Currently, if I have over 1000 users the logic continues and gives me an index undefined error. This makes sense since the index would be 13 and the array would only be 12.** This does not make sense to me though?

Comment: I'm also confused how `ParticipantCount` is related at all to `index`.  Why would having > 1000 users cause an index undefined error?  The code snippets so far don't seem to show how/why that would be possible.  Other questions:  where is the control logic called from?  What line of code actually gives the "index undefined" error?